# How to make this Javascript more compact

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a snippet of a Javascript I'm using. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it more compact. It changes CSS, but the most classes have the same values (and the actual js is very long now).

```
$('#project_planetx').mouseover(function() {
   $('#project_bg_show').css("background-image", "url(images/projects/WeT_PLXT_branding.png)").css("background-size", "cover"); // change css
   $('#projects_header_show').css("color", "transparent");
   $('.projects_headercolom_show').css("color", "transparent");
   $('.blvd_headercolom_show').css("color", "transparent");
   $('.project_b').css("display", "none");  
   $('.project_c').css("display", "none");              
});

$('#project_planetx').mouseleave(function() {
   $('#project_bg_show').css("background", "#FAFAFA").css("background-image", "url(images/projects/Projects_BG_main.png)").css("background-size", "cover");; // change back css as it was
   $('#projects_header_show').css("color", "#000000");
   $('.projects_headercolom_show').css("color", "#000000");
   $('.blvd_headercolom_show').css("color", "#000000");
   $('.project_b').css("display", "block"); 
   $('.project_c').css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select different elements at the same time if you will apply the same CSS for them. Use a comma to separate your elements. Here is the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
$('#projects_header_show,.projects_headercolom_show,.blvd_headercolom_show').css("color", "transparent");
$('.project_b,.project_c').css("display", "none");
//you continue with the rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an object out of all the attributes and id/classNames. Whether or not you think this is better is up to you. It's not more compact, but it's definitely DRY.

edit: It's not more DRY. Just a definitely design choice. One I like more.

```
   $('#project_bg_show').css("background-image", "url(images/projects/WeT_PLXT_branding.png)").css("background-size", "cover"); // change css
    $('#projects_header_show').css("color", "transparent");
    $('.projects_headercolom_show').css("color", "transparent");
    $('.blvd_headercolom_show').css("color", "transparent");

const styles = {
  ['#project_bg_show']: {
    attr1: "background-image",
    attr2: "url(images/projects/WeT_PLXT_branding.png)"
  },
  ['#projects_header_show']: {
    attr1: "background-image",
    attr2: "url(images/projects/WeT_PLXT_branding.png)"
  },
  ['.projects_headercolom_show']: {
  attr1: "color"
    attr2: "transparent"
  }
}

for (let domElement of styles) {
  let {attr1, attr2} = styles[domElement]
  $(domElement).css(attr1, attr2)
}
```

Comment: "it's definitely DRY" --- DRY is not about repeating statements, but about repeating *knowledge*.

Comment: @zerkms You're right. Edited. What are your thoughts about this approach? I feel like it's more maintainable, as you will never be tempted to copy/paste and will only add exactly what you need if you need to change it.

Comment: I totally find it MUCH harder to understand.

Comment: @zerkms A fair assessment. A third person perspective is always helpful. I'll be more mindful of how/when I do something like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can make it more compact:

```
$(document).on({
  mouseover: function() {
    $('#project_bg_show').css({
      "background-image": "url(images/projects/WeT_PLXT_branding.png)",
      "background-size": "cover",
    }); // change css
    $('.blvd_headercolom_show, .projects_headercolom_show, #projects_header_show').css("color", "transparent");
    $('.project_b,.project_c').css("display", "none");
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('#project_bg_show').css({
      "background": "#FAFAFA",
      "background-image": "url(images/projects/Projects_BG_main.png)",
      "background-size": "cover"
    }); // change back css as it was
    $('.blvd_headercolom_show, .projects_headercolom_show, #projects_header_show').css("color", "#000000");
    $('.project_c, .project_b').css("display", "block");
  }
}, '#project_planetx');
```